# MySQL fulltext inadequate. Creating an index would exceed 1000 bytes limit. What to do then?

Tags: mysql, indexing, full-text-search, limit

Here are the columns involved:

```
order_id int(8)

tracking_number char(13)

carrier_status varchar(128)

recipient_name varchar(128)

recipient_address varchar(256)

recipient_state varchar(32)

recipient_country_descr varchar(128)

recipient_zipcode varchar(32)
```

Getting this error when I try to create an index of all these columns:

MySQL #1071 - Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes

What can I do given that this index is very important for the database?

I need to allow users to search all fields from a form with a single search field. So I'm using this query:

```
WHERE CONCAT(tracking_number, recipient_name, recipient_address, recipient_state, recipient_country_descr, recipient_zipcode, order_id, carrier_status) LIKE '$keyword1'
```

I've also considered using fulltext match() against(). Problem was that it doesn't allow searches like *keyword so I scratched it and am doing it with simple LIKE %keyword1% AND LIKE %keyword2% for each keyword.

But now I've ran into another problem, the query may be slow as I cannot create a single index containing all columns that will be searched.

What to do in this situation?

Comment: Is this a MyISAM table or mysql 5.6?  Did you add a fulltext index into the column(s) you're trying to do match with?

Comment: Can you post your table's create statement?  `SHOW CREATE TABLE  <tablename>`

Comment: table is MyISAM , MySQL v.5.1.57 , UTF-8 collation , if still need the create table info I will post but it's a little big...

Comment: The create statement from `SHOW CREATE TABLE <tablename>` is large?  How many columns are in your table?

Comment: Why do you think a combined index would help you?

Comment: It has 39 columns but only 8 are used on this query

Comment: Yes I thought a single combined index of all 8 columns would be the optimal index. What are the alternatives? Leaving it without any index or making multiple smaller indexes?

Comment: Someone said that indexes can't be used with concat() , is that true? If so how to optimize this query? Am I stuck with a slow query or having to look for a search engine like Lucene?

Comment: @user3746280 MySQL currently won't use an index for a calculated value. Furthermore can't MySQL use an index for queries with `LIKE '%keyword`.

Comment: @VMai So nothing I can do to optimize this query? Would you recommend anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A conventional B-tree index cannot help when you're searching for a keyword that may be in multiple columns, or may be in the middle of a string.

Think of a telephone book. It's like an index on `(last name, first name)`. If I ask you to search for a certain last name, it helps a lot that the book is already sorted that way. If I ask you to search for a specific last name and first name combination, the sort order of the book is also helpful.

But if I ask you to search for someone only by a specific first name "Bill", the fact that the book is sorted is not helpful. Occurrences of "Bill" could be found anywhere in the book, so you basically have to read it cover-to-cover.

Likewise if I ask you to search for anyone's name that contains a certain substring in the middle of the name or at the end. For example, anyone's last name that ends in "-son".

Your example of using CONCAT() over a bunch of columns and comparing that to a keyword in a `LIKE` pattern has the same problem.

The solution is to use a fulltext search engine, which *does* offer the ability to search for words anywhere in the middle of strings. It indexes in a completely different way than the one-dimensional B-tree sorting.

If you don't find that MySQL's `FULLTEXT` index is flexible enough (and I wouldn't blame you because MySQL's implementation is pretty rudimentary), then I suggest you look at a more specialized search technology. Here are a few free software options:

- [Apache Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/)
- [Sphinx Search](http://sphinxsearch.com/)
- [Xapian](http://xapian.org/)

This may mean that you have to copy the searchable text from MySQL to the search engine, and keep copying it incrementally as changes are made to your MySQL data. A lot of developers do this.

Comment: I think I will stick with this solution and see how far it can take me.

If it starts getting too slow I will probably add some RAM to the server or implement the Solr engine.

Thanks Bill and other who commented!